# My central heating comes on when it feels like it

Tags: thermostat, heating, boiler

I have checked the wireless thermostat is sending a demand signal to the receiver but boiler isn't firing up (*BTW my hot water on demand is working fine*).

Later on the heating comes on until I turn it off.

It is as if there's some blockage that suddenly gives way, but it can't be blocked if it works when it wants to.

It's a Worcester Greenstar Junior combi with Drayton wireless thermostat and it has been working perfectly up until this although I haven't needed to the put the heating on in probably 6 months or so. I haven't made any changes to it.

Comment: Not enough info. Did it work fine before and just started this, did you change something or did this happen when you installed the wireless?  What brand thermostat, boiler etc.? Use the edit button to add as much detail as you can.

Comment: From the "Never hurts to check the obvious" department: Is the interior air temp falling below the heating set point on the thermostat? Is it at least 2°-3°  below, maybe as much as 5°? (There's usually a "dead range" so your furnace isn't cycling constantly trying to maintain an exact temperature.) Also, presumably, it was controlling heating just fine last spring? You mention hot water - are they out of the same unit? Have you checked the heater for loose connections?

Comment: thanks for the reply. No it has been quite cold and i've asked it to come on much higher. Hot water is from the same unit yes. It was fine before yes.